# pyinotify return value from handled event

Tags: python, pyinotify

I'm trying to return a value from handled method. I'm very newbie using pyinotify, the code is:

```
import pyinotify
import time


wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
mask = pyinotify.IN_OPEN

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    endGame = False
    def process_IN_OPEN(self, event):
        print "Opening:", event.pathname
        endGame = True

handler = EventHandler()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)

wdd = wm.add_watch('./file.json', mask, rec=True)
wm.rm_watch(wdd.values())

while not handler.endGame:
    time.sleep(1)

notifier.stop()
print "end game"
```

But when I open file.json, the endGame variable never turns to True. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your handler. Let's look at the code (I'll add comments to significant lines):

```
class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    endGame = False   # Here class attribute "endGame" is declared

    def process_IN_OPEN(self, event):
        print "Opening:", event.pathname
        endGame = True  # Here !local variable! is defined process_IN_OPEN
```

So, you define new variable in the scope of `process_IN_OPEN` method. You need to add self if you want to refer to `EventHandler` instance attribute:

```
self.endGame = True
```

Comment: @papelucho, if the answer helps, please mark your question as answered so it could help other people encountering same problem.